# Using custom variable in Less function

Tags: css, less

I'm having some trouble using a less variable into a less function.
My code looks like this :

```
@primaryColor: "#fff";
@customColor: darken(@primaryColor, 5%);
```

But I'm getting the following error :

> Error evaluating function `darken`: Argument cannot be evaluated to a color

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `#fff` :

```
@primaryColor: #fff;
@customColor: darken(@primaryColor, 5%);
```